# Have multiple pipeline triggers in Azure

Tags: azure-yaml-pipelines

I have a pipeline, let's call it c. I would like c to be triggered if either pipeline a or pipeline b finishes. Please see bellow my attempt. Anyone knows why it does not work?

```
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: a
      source: ci-a
      trigger:
        branches:
          - '*'
    - pipeline: ci-b
      source: b
      trigger:
        branches:
          - '*'
```

Answer (score 1):

Should work like this

```
resources:
  pipelines: 
  - pipeline:  Trigger-A #This is an alias 
    source:  ci-a #name of pipeline that you want to be triggering this pipeline
    trigger:
      branches: #Branches to include
      - *
  - pipeline:  Trigger-B
    source:  ci-b
    trigger:
      branches: 
      - *
```